# What image format is this?

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64, rgba

I copied data from canvas element on my page (using getImageData()) and got an RGB array, which is 4-bytes per pixel (RGB and Alpha).

What image format it actually is?

I need to create an Image element and to do so I have to convert it to data URL using some prefix, such as:

src="data:image/png;base64,...

What should I paste instead of image/png for RGBa array?

Comment: And how did you copy the image from the canvas exactly ?

Comment: sounds like a raw bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

To get a data URL of the current canvas there is a canvas function: canvas.toDataURL();
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

The default filetype is png.

Comment: toDataURL is limited on iOS as I know so I would better use something else. Just wanted to find out what mime type should I paste in data string.

Comment: You can't paste the plain Array or String and give it a mime-type. You could build a Bitmap-File out of it.
http://blog.paphus.com/blog/2012/08/14/write-your-own-bitmaps/

Comment: Is it unusual task to display an image from raw RGB data? I'm new to web technologies.. I just want to create an Image instance from that RGB.